# Can concurrency issues occur when doing MySQL query update to value + 1?

Tags: mysql, concurrency

If I have the following SQL:

```
update clients set credits = credits - 1
```

If this is repeatedly executed, can there ever be a case where concurrency could occur. In other words, does MySQL cater for concurrency internally, or could this cause issues if the sql is executed concurrently by multiple parties?

Comment: [See here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166242/mysql-will-a-transaction-lock-the-row) for a better explanation than I could give myself.  The answer is that MySQL will wrap your single `UPDATE` in a transaction, which should then block any other thread which wants to update the same record, until your first `UPDATE` has completed.